# tkinter .grid() geometry manager is not outputing the right Frame serial

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to have three `Frame`(s) to make a table of buttons. But I couldn't think of any way to make it work somehow. Changing the serial of the Frames will mess everything up.

1. First, each button will get his own `Frame` - `ForEach()` method.
2. Second, each row will be under a `Frame` - `ForEachRow()` method.
3. Third, all rows and columns are in a single `Frame` - `ForWhole()` method.

But when I run the code the result shows the image below [output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjnuf.png). I just don't get the order of the table in the output. Because I want

1. `ForEach()` to be in the top and then
2. `ForEachRow()` and
3. `ForWhole()` in the bottom.

But if I change the serial of the tables in my code then first row or column gets separated from **red** or **yellow** table or from **both**.

This kind of output shows when  the serial is `ForWhole()` -> `ForEach()` -> `ForEachRow()` [messed up output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPEL6.png). What is going on with this code?

`ForWhole()`->`ForEachRow()`->`ForEach` [gives this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbn55.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

row = int(input("Enter the number of row: "))
col = int(input("Enter the number of cols: "))

def ForEach():
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            frame3 = tk.Frame(
                master=window,
                relief=tk.RIDGE,
                borderwidth=5,
                bg="red",
            )
            frame3.grid(row=i,column=j)
            button = tk.Button(
                relief=tk.RAISED,
                master=frame3,
                text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}",
                bg="cyan",
            )
            button.pack()

def ForEachRow():
    for i in range(row):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(
            master=window,
            relief=tk.RIDGE,
            borderwidth=5,
            bg="yellow",
        )
        frame1.grid(row=i)
        for j in range(col):
            button = tk.Button(
                relief=tk.RIDGE,
                master=frame1,
                text=f'Row {i}\nColumn {j}',
                bg="cyan"
            )
            button.grid(row=i,column=j)

def ForWhole():
    frame2 = tk.Frame(
        master = window,
        relief=tk.RIDGE,
        borderwidth=5,
        bg="blue"
    )
    frame2.grid()
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            button = tk.Button(
                relief=tk.RAISED,
                master=frame2,
                text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}",
                bg="cyan",
            )
            button.grid(row=i,column=j)
ForEach()
ForEachRow()
ForWhole()
```

Comment: Since all frames are children of `window`, so the frames created at column 0 inside `ForEach()` will be covered by the frames created at column 0 inside `ForEachRow()`.  You need to supply an offset row to `ForEachRow()` and `ForWhole()`.

Comment: Or use two outer frames to hold the frames in `ForEach()` and `ForEachRow()`.

Comment: one outer frame solves the problem for `ForEach()` but `ForEachRow()` separates it's rows (like each row starts below the last cell of the row above).